# Can't get Firebase Crashlytics to work - not connecting to dashboard

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I cannot get Firebase crashlytics to work on iOS with swift. I have created a new app and a new Firebase project. (The app-server connection is succefull - I have checked it by creating a dummy firestore and read from it)

I have followed all the steps as detailed in the Firestore docs:

1. Added the `Firebase/Crashlytics` pod
2. Added the `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"` script in the project build phases
3. Selected the `dwarf-with-dsym` configuration
4. Forced a crash with `fatalError`
5. Run the app with no debugger attached

From the Firebase dashboard Crashlytics page I can only see the the rotating wheel and I do not get the successful installation.

This is XCode error stack when I launch the app:

```
2021-02-07 20:09:09.672258+0100 crashlyticsTest[43062:2323253] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 7.4.0
2021-02-07 20:09:09.874008+0100 crashlyticsTest[43062:2323510] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2021-02-07 20:09:09.918388+0100 crashlyticsTest[43062:2323514] 7.4.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Failed to remove file /Users/lucasfragara/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73D5BD20-51E0-4346-8474-375D5018108E/data/Containers/Data/Application/47F2BB34-CB6D-4E08-93B3-CCFC00788DA4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.sfra.crashlyticsTest/v5/reports/prepared/ad561f8c3ef74f6fb5cdf1eadb3bae7d: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“ad561f8c3ef74f6fb5cdf1eadb3bae7d” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSFilePath=/Users/lucasfragara/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73D5BD20-51E0-4346-8474-375D5018108E/data/Containers/Data/Application/47F2BB34-CB6D-4E08-93B3-CCFC00788DA4/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.sfra.crashlyticsTest/v5/reports/prepared/ad561f8c3ef74f6fb5cdf1eadb3bae7d, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002b294a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
2021-02-07 20:09:09.918775+0100 crashlyticsTest[43062:2323514] 7.4.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unable to remove packaged submission
Fatal error: file crashlyticsTest/ViewController.swift, line 14
2021-02-07 20:09:09.926357+0100 crashlyticsTest[43062:2323253] Fatal error: file crashlyticsTest/ViewController.swift, line 14
(lldb)
```